# Python equation solver(energy balances) not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried making a program that asks for 2 types of energy(e.g. kinetic energy...) and uses those formulas to complete the parameters that were given. E.g. I would give in kinetic energy formula, the mass, and the speed would be the missing one. Then I would enter the potential energy formula, the mass, and the height, and per conservation of energy the amount of energy in the system should remain the same. The program should then have solved the equation for the missing parameter(in this case speed) but it doesn't work and just spits out errors. Underneath you can see the code and the errors that result. This isn't the full code, just a smallpart of it.

Code:

```py
def ask_equations():
    global inp_1
    global inp_2

    inp_1 = str(input("Wählen sie den ersten Energietyp: "))
    inp_2 = str(input("Wählen sie den zweiten Energietyp: "))

def check_equations():
    if inp_1 == "Lageenergie":

        print("Lageenergie:")
        print("m * g * h")

        m_1 = float(input("Masse des Objekts(1)"))

        if m_1 == "-":
            m_1 = Symbol("m_1")

        h_1 = float(input("Höhe des Objekts(1)"))

        if h_1 == "-":
            h_1 = Symbol("h_1")

        equation_1 = m_1 * g * h_1


    if inp_2 == "Lageenergie":

        print("Lageenergie:")
        print("m * g * h")

        m_2 = float(input("Masse des Objekts(2)"))

        if m_2 == "-":
            m_2 = Symbol("m_2")

        h_2 = input("Höhe des Objekts(2)")

        if h_2 == "-":
            h_2 = Symbol("h_2")

        equation_2 = m_2 * g * h_2


def solver():
    print(to_be_found)

    x = solve(equation_1 - equation_2, to_be_found)

    print(to_be_found)

def execute():
    ask_equations()

    check_equations()

    solver()

execute()
```

Error code:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Name\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\sympify.py", line 385, in sympify
    expr = parse_expr(a, local_dict=locals, transformations=transformations, evaluate=evaluate)
  File "C:\Users\Name\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\parsing\sympy_parser.py", line 1008, in parse_expr
    return eval_expr(code, local_dict, global_dict)
  File "C:\Users\Name\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\parsing\sympy_parser.py", line 903, in eval_expr
    code, global_dict, local_dict)  # take local objects in preference
  File "<string>", line 0

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Name/PycharmProjects/sympy/physics.py", line 201, in <module>
    execute()
  File "C:/Users/Name/PycharmProjects/sympy/physics.py", line 199, in execute
    solver()
  File "C:/Users/Name/PycharmProjects/sympy/physics.py", line 189, in solver
    x = solve(equation_1 - equation_2, to_be_found)
  File "C:\Users\Name\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\solvers.py", line 925, in solve
    f, symbols = (_sympified_list(w) for w in [f, symbols])
  File "C:\Users\Name\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\solvers.py", line 925, in <genexpr>
    f, symbols = (_sympified_list(w) for w in [f, symbols])
  File "C:\Users\Name\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\solvers.py", line 916, in _sympified_list
    return list(map(sympify, w if iterable(w) else [w]))
  File "C:\Users\Name\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\sympify.py", line 387, in sympify
    raise SympifyError('could not parse %r' % a, exc)
sympy.core.sympify.SympifyError: Sympify of expression 'could not parse ''' failed, because of exception being raised:
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing (<string>, line 0)
```

Comment: That is not the code producing those errors. If you simplify the code, make sure you post the errors that result from the simplified code.

Comment: be specific please